# CSS Video + Image Gallery in one

Tags: css, image, video, gallery, responsive

[website pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTKfc.jpg) I wanted to re-design my website.

So a side by side 2 pictures but the first boxed picture is where i put the links to the video: part 1 - part 2 like that with a photo of the video above and then to the right another photo that has text saying view gallery.
Then repeat this responsive for every video.

I would love to have pretty buttons but google page speed said it couldn't see them clearly so i just stayed with text.

thanks

Comment: My brain just exploded trying to understand what you're looking to do. What's the main question? If you can't come up with code at least come up with an example in paint so we have something to work with

Comment: Video photograph with text links below where they download the parts of the video.  And gallery photograph/gif with text link below that goes to gallery page.  and also have that on top of a grey box that fits both of the pictures and text on